# How to enable the debug mode in TestExecute tool

Tags: testcomplete

I am executing tests through TestExecute and I want to enable the debug mode, i.e. I want it to pause at all the breakpoints which are set in the TestComplete project suite that is being executed using TestExecute.

I have searched a lot and unable to find a solution...Hopefully I'll get help here :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my bad news but this feature (debug mode) is not supported by TestExecute.
TestExecute its a tool only to execute the testcases. In order to debug the code, make new implementations and everything else, you must buy a TestComplete license.
This is the reason of the prices between them (TestExecute its 2x cheaper than TestComplete).
In fact TestExecute its a part of TestComplete.

Comment: Hi Chiri. Thanks for the response....I already have both the licenses...bu our framework is such that while the tests are running...it invokes test execute which further runs the tests in the Test Complete project suite...while I can debug from TestComplete, I wanted to see the parameters flowing in at run-time....that was the intent....

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response though :) Now I can stop searching for a solution and live with debugging through TestComplete...